# What exactly is "Overridden", "Needs review" & "Revert component" in Features?

Tags: features

I can see `Overridden`, `Needs review` & `Revert component` in [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).

If I want to get latest updated features always, what I will do?

What `drush fr, drush fu` will do internally?

What I understood is, `overridden` is the state where our current config/settings changed with new features. If we do `revert component`, all the new changes will be reflected. So here what is the drush command shall I use?.

Anyone can explain all these three?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both **needs review** and **overridden** statuses mean that the feature in the database does not match the feature in code. Running **"drush fr"** (feature revert) will replace the feature in the database with the feature in code.

Now lets see **"Revert" vs "Update"**

**Revert:**(drush fr)

This operation changes your site configuration (living in the database) to match up with the definitions in the feature module code.

**Update / Recreate**:(drush fu)

The update operation will produce a modified version of your feature module, which matches up with the configuration found in the database.

> Remember, revert for Drupal features means copy configuration from
>   code into the database.

If you want to go in detail with simple explanation, then please follow below links

1. [Modifying, updating and reverting Features](https://www.drupal.org/node/582680)
2. [Revert and update a Drupal feature module](http://befused.com/drupal/feature-update-revert)

Answer (score 3):

## Feature states

**Default**: Everything contained in the feature matches the site's database.

**Overridden**: Something used in the site no longer matches the state of it as contained in the feature.

**Needs review**: This is the same state as **Overridden**, but it means there are more complicated changes and you should review the differences prior to reverting the feature. Remark: use the [Features Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_diff) module to simplify the investigation of the changes.

## Feature actions

**Revert**: reverting an overridden feature makes the site settings match those in the feature again. This is equivalent to using drush cmd `drush fr`.

**Update**: updating a feature makes the feature match (in synch with) the site settings. This is equivalent to using drush cmd `drush fu`.

## Video tutorials

- [Creating a Feature](http://wunderkraut.com/content/creating-a-feature).
- [Reverting Features](http://wunderkraut.com/content/reverting-features).
- [Updating Features](http://wunderkraut.com/content/updating-features).